# easiest way to do this? (Amplifier Grid)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

i finished full donat tutorial. and im wondering can u tell me the easiest way to do it ? I tried modeling myself with path and using array model but it doesnt look right becouse i cant do it to look evenly across.

any tips ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think, if it is not tooo close, you sould try to do it with a Texture because that pattern full poly would take a lot of render time...

Comment: thx man i will try that !

Comment: @M.Matz agreed.. the best way, if not too close-up.. and re-usable, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Robin Betts inspired me a simplification. You could do it with arrayed meshes:

- Build your segment, move up the middle with the *Proportional Editing* option, duplicate and turn it upside down.

[image]

- Give it 2 *Array* modifiers to duplicate the segments on the X and Y axis. Duplicate and rotate the whole thing 180°.

[image]

- Keep a copy somewhere, rotate all 45° on the Z axis, apply the modifiers, join everything, delete the mesh so you only keep a square grid.

[image]

- To finish, curve the edges with a *Curve* modifier.

[image]

Comment: how do i delete all mesh  so i can keep square grid ?

Comment: Once you've applied the modifiers, joined the objects to make one unique mesh, use the box selection (B) to select the parts you want to delete, and only keep a square grid. Does it answer?

Comment: dooah, THANKS ! really appreaciated!

Answer (score 2):

So  I think, the best way is the suggestion with a normal map or something if you can find such a texture.

Another method, if these polygons are realy needed is something like that. You could make this with a view curve, a aray modifier and maybe with a shrink wrap modifier or a curve modifier to fit it to the model. [image: model]

Maybe you also could make with such an mesh your own normal map if you bake that normals to your model but you need to figure out how that works on your own. Somthing like that but in your case it is an different model. But with normal or displaycement maps you will save a lot of time.

Comment: Tested, it works....

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers they are great ! unfortunately i tried to use with texture image but i cuoldn't make it becouse of the image quality, or my lack of understanding shading with bumps and such.

Comment: @LucidNirvana It just came me in mind that this problem couldn't be solved so well with a normal map because for that grid, at some points you would need 2 pixels to represent that grid stucture,but with that normal map you could only display on normal at one pixel and not two...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bad place to use the shipped Tissue add-on.

After you install it, (Edit > Preferences > Add-Ons,) it will appear as a tab in the <kbd>N</kbd> properties region of the 3D View. It has a 'Tessellate' option which will duplicate and map a Component (selected) object to the Base (active) object's quad faces.

[image]

This example starts with the top sliced off a cube, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> beveled, and then with its main faces subdivided.

To get the diagonals, the object is  (Edge menu > Un-Subdivided) with 1 iteration.

The diagonal mesh is then used as a base for tessellating the Component on the left, which is a mesh converted from a curve, which was thickened by bevelling it in its Data > Geometry panel.

Comment: You mean "Tissue" addon?

Comment: @lemon Oops! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that addon helped me also with an project for printing.